# JSF Command Button not redirecting correctly

Tags: jsf

I'm doing a web project with JSP and JSF.  I have a table with multiple rows and each row has a edit Button. But when I click on the Edit Button the redirecting is not working.

Table in listaTeatros.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable id="teatros" 
             summary="Lista de Teatros"
             value="#{teatroBean.listaTeatros}"
             var="teatro"
             class="thead-teatro">
    <h:column >
        <f:facet name="header" class="thead-teatro">
            < h:outputText value="Nome"  class="thead-teatro-li"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="nomeTeatro" value="#{teatro.nome}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header" class="thead-teatro">
            <h:outputText value="Cidade" class="thead-teatro-li" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="teatroCidade" value="#{teatro.cidade}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header" class="thead-teatro">
            <h:outputText value="Email" class="thead-teatro-li"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="teatroEmail" value="#{teatro.email}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header" class="thead-teatro">
            <h:outputText value="CNPJ" class="thead-teatro-li"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="teatroCNPJ" value="#{teatro.cnpj}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column> 
        <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>  
            <h:commandButton id="edita" value="Edita"
                action="#{teatroBean.editaTeatro(teatro.id)}" /> //ERROR IS HERE 
    </h:column>  

</h:dataTable>
```

teatroBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
    public class TeatroBean implements Serializable {

    private Teatro teatro = new Teatro();

    public TeatroBean(){

    }

    public String lista() {
        return "listaTeatros";
    }

    public String cadastra() {

        return "formsCadastrarTeatros.xhtml";
    }

    public String editaTeatro(int id) {
        TeatroDAO dao = new TeatroDAO();
        teatro = dao.get(id);

        return "formsCadastrarTeatros.xhtml";
    }
}
```

teatroBean.editaTeatro(int id) is not redirecting to "formsCadastrarTeatros.xhtml".

Comment: _"teatroBean.editaTeatro(int id) is not redirecting to "formsCadastrarTeatros.xhtml"."_ But what *IS* it doing? And did you try without a datatable? And how is this JPA related? I don't see anything JPA in here (and more important, 99.5 percent of the questions that have both JPA and JSF in the question are related to just one. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: It's redirecting to the same page but without any rows in the table (??) I really dont understand... I'm using glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: Really redirecting? So pn ypur submit (http post) you see a response of the server and the client doing a new get of the same page? so a 'post-redirect-get'

Comment: I'm suspecting that `@RequestScoped` bean - tried with a `@ViewScoped`?